# What does 1071: Syntax error indicate and how do I resolve this code?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm going through tutorials on dynamic classes.  The concept is really exciting and interesting to me.

However this code isn't compiling correctly

```
dynamic class Person {
var name:String;
}

Person p= new Person();
p.name=”Joe”;
p.age=25;
p.printMe = function () {
trace (p.name, p.age);
}
p.printMe(); // Joe 25
```

I get a 1071 syntax error.

What gives?

Comment: `Person p= new Person();` is `var p:Person = new Person();` in as3

Comment: A syntax error simply means there's some kind of typing mistake in your code (the syntax).

Comment: @www0z0k Doesn't work, I already tried that.

Comment: @LedZeppelin Well, BoltClock was answering the first part of your question ("What does 1071: Syntax error indicate") directly.  Don't be so snarky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error in syntax; `Person p = new Person();` is not valid AS3. It should be `var p:Person = new Person();"`

EDIT 1:
Also, of course if you put your code as-is in the timeline it will not work. The class has to be in a .as file, and the other code must be in the timeline (or in a class function).

EDIT 2:
This code works:

```
//Timeline:
var p:Person = new Person();
p.name="Joe";
p.age=25;
p.printMe = function () {
    trace (p.name, p.age);
}
p.printMe(); // Joe 25`
```

Where Person.as looks like:

```
package {
    public dynamic class Person {
        var name:String;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jonatan, I'm working through it now (sorry I'm a slow newb.) Btw why can't you have classes in the timeline?

Comment: Internally it's probably because the timeline is a part of an automatically generated class, and you can't have classes in classes. It's just how it is :)

Comment: Ah thanks, also one last thing.  Does the name of the .as file always have to be the same as the class inside the .as file?

Comment: +1 Also note that the double quotes that were copied are the wrong double quotes.  `"Joe"` instead of `”Joe”`.

Comment: Yeah, it's another limitation on how the compiler finds the relevant files.

Comment: @JonatanHedborg Sounds good, so I take it you can't have more than 1 class in an .as file?

Comment: Well you can, but it's complicated and weird. There can only be one public class (useable from outside the file) per .as file.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it right now, but it looks like there are two errors in your code snippet. First, the variable declaration and second the string quotes (you used `”` instead of `"`). The following code *should* work:

```
var p:Person = new Person();
p.name = "Joe";
p.age = 25;
p.printMe = function() {
    trace (p.name, p.age);
}
p.printMe(); // Joe 25
```